# error with symspell spell corrector function

Tags: python, spell-checking

I'm trying to build a spell corrector but it's not working correctly.

Code from: https://www.kaggle.com/yk1598/symspell-spell-corrector/script

```
def spell_corrector(word_list, words_d) -> str:
  result_list = []
  for word in word_list:
    if word not in words_d:
      suggestion = ss.best_word(word, silent=True)
      if suggestion is not None:
        result_list.append(suggestion)
      else:
        result_list.append(word)
            
  return " ".join(result_list)

def spell_check(text):
  ss = SymSpell(max_edit_distance=2)
    
  with open('corpus.txt') as bf:
    words = bf.readlines()
    chatbot_words = [word.strip() for word in words]    

  all_words_list = list(set(chatbot_words))
  silence = ss.create_dictionary_from_arr(all_words_list, token_pattern=r'.+')
    
  words_dict = {k: 0 for k in all_words_list}
    
  tokens = spacy_tokenize(message)
  

  correct_text = spell_corrector(tokens, words_dict)
  return correct_text

message = input("") 
spell_check(message)
```

The error I got was this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-8d527844467a> in <module>()
    330 message = input("")
--> 331 spell_check(message)

1 frames
<ipython-input-8-8d527844467a> in spell_corrector(word_list, words_d)
    301   for word in word_list:
    302     if word not in words_d:
--> 303       suggestion = ss.best_word(word, silent=True)
    304       if suggestion is not None:
    305         result_list.append(suggestion)

NameError: name 'ss' is not defined
```

I can't figure out the error can someone help me out on this? I've already tried putting

```
ss = SymSpell(max_edit_distance=2)
```

Under the `spell_corrector` function but it returns the incorrect input words instead of the corrected text

Answer (score 1):

Try defining `ss` variable outside the function like this:

```
ss = SymSpell(max_edit_distance=2)

def spell_corrector(word_list, words_d) -> str:
  result_list = []
  for word in word_list:
    if word not in words_d:
      suggestion = ss.best_word(word, silent=True)
      if suggestion is not None:
        result_list.append(suggestion)
      else:
        result_list.append(word)
            
  return " ".join(result_list)

def spell_check(text):
  with open('corpus.txt') as bf:
    words = bf.readlines()
    chatbot_words = [word.strip() for word in words]    

  all_words_list = list(set(chatbot_words))
  silence = ss.create_dictionary_from_arr(all_words_list, token_pattern=r'.+')
    
  words_dict = {k: 0 for k in all_words_list}
    
  tokens = spacy_tokenize(message)
  

  correct_text = spell_corrector(tokens, words_dict)
  return correct_text

message = input("") 
spell_check(message)
```

Comment: just tried this but it still gives me returns the incorrect words in the string instead of the corrected sentence

Comment: @elizzz Can you provide the `corpus.txt` file in the question?